# BrowserSync not working with laravel-elixir

Tags: laravel, browser-sync

I read the doc in www.laravel.com about how to run browserSync with laravel-elixir and , but I find it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

after i run many tests, i found a solution which work for me.
I hope this solution also help others:

I just place following code before

```
</body>
```

tag, and it works.

```
<script id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
                            document.write("<script async src='http://HOST:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.12.5.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>
```